# Intent Flag doesn't work for physical button in android

Tags: android, android-intent, activity-lifecycle, onpause, ondestroy

I want to create a simple app which having two activities... And I want to jump one activity from another without performing **OnDestroy();** I want there to happen **OnPause();**

I can achieve it by using a flah like below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(secondActivity.this, firstSecond.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

But the flag only works on the **BackButton** Which is inside the current activity. If I click back button in my mobile the flag doesn't work..... what should I do???? any help??

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `onBackPressed()` and execute the same code instead:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(secondActivity.this, firstSecond.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```